# Backbone click event not binding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to js/backbone and can't get this click event to work. Does anyone have any thoughts or direction? Here is my code so far:

```
(function(){

window.BtnApp = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {}
};

window.template = function(id){
    return _.template( $('#' + id).html());
};

BtnApp.Models.Button = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    tagName: 'button',
    className: 'testbutton'
});

btn = new BtnApp.Models.Button;


BtnApp.Views.Button = Backbone.View.extend ({

    events: {
    'click h1' : 'logged'
    },
    cssred: function() {
        $('h1').css('color', 'red');
        console.log('what se fugg');
        return this;
    },
    logged: function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    return this;
    }



});
btnView = new BtnApp.Views.Button({ model: btn })
})();
```

Comment: You need to bind the view to an element in the DOM, then call the `render()` method

Comment: `tagName` and `className` are view properties, not model properties.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using template like that, so take this with a grain of salt, but it looks like inside your `BtnApp.Views.Button` you don't have an `h1` element within the scope of that view. Try saying `this.$el.append('<h1>Click</h1>')` and test that. That should work :)

Comment: @muistooshort has helped me countless times when I was learning backbone, so I would take his advice. I'm not an expert yet, but that's what I would do! Check out structuring your app using marionette, makes it easier and cleaner just a thought!

Comment: And @Bojangles advice as well. Your view isn't bound to anything in the DOM so you'll never be clicking on anything that the view will know about. Have a look at this version of your code and you'll see what Bojangles is talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8877E/

Comment: Oh yeah you need to `render()` that element first, then your code will be able to run the click event so `render: function() { this.$el.append('<h1>Click</h1>') return this}, ` use `return this` inside the render method.

Comment: there is an h1 tag in the html this is being used on. Am I not binding it correctly with  $('h1').css('color', 'red');  Unfortunately I am confused by your fiddle, since your instantiating, and I am calling the tag from the html